# Power of two bufferSize

Tags: android, signal-processing

384I was searching for a way to record to a power of two file size, and i found [this](http://therandomlab.blogspot.fr/2013/05/fft-audio-frequency-analysis-with.html)

It works well but i don't know what is the meaning of this equation:

```
 bufferSize =  2 << (int)(log(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE)/log(2)-1);
```

i am a bit familiar with signed shifting in java but i dont get the same output. It gives a buffer size of 16384 samples. i want to reduce it.

Comment: Can you bring the relevant parts of the code from the link to this question? It seems like a decent question, but is still probably going to get closed as is because of the reliance on off-site resources.

Comment: the purpose is clear, most available fast FFTs require power of 2 file lengths, and if you use AudioRecorder's buffer it doesnt give you that requirement, so this equation is to generate power of two buffers to make it easier to record files that later can be fed to the FFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you choose `2^(log(2048) / log(2))` its give to you 2048 samples per buffer if your frame rate is 44100 you record 464 miliseconds == `2048/44100 = 0.0464`

It is just a different way to create your `bufferSize` you can put directly power of two values in your `bufferSize` variable ( 1024, 2048, 4096, etc)

Comment: thanks alot for the answer :) it is what im looking for